# How to display return value in web in a label or web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to display return value in web in a label or web browser?
The code:

```
public static string FormatTelephoneNumber(string value)
{
    value = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\D").Replace(value, string.Empty);
    value = value.TrimStart('1');

    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) && (value.Length >= 12))
        return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("{0:+234 ### ### ####}");
    if (value.Length == 10)
        return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("{0:+1 ### ### ####}");
    if (value.Length != 10)
        return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("0:+44 ###-###-#### " + new String('#', (value.Length - 10)));
    if (value.Length == 10)
        return Convert.ToInt64(value).ToString("{0:+233 ### ### ###}");

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Mode details please. What kind of project is that mvc or webforms?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I'm not sure where is the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a Web Forms project (since you didn't provide any details in your question)

Code Behind (.aspx.cs)

```
string input="5555555555";
MyLabel.Text = FormatTelephoneNumber(input);
```

Page (.aspx)

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="MyLabel" />
```

Simply assign it to the text of the label. If you need more help, you should explain what you're trying to ask in your question, and explain what you've tried.

Comment: it works only with 11digits ..How do test it for 10 and 7digits number?

Comment: @user3849239 You should ask that as a separate question, as that is unrelated to the current one.